# Blockquote adds extra <br>

Tags: css, blockquote

Why blockquote adds a extra br at the end of it and how can i avoid it?
How can i remove that extra br that is added so all my lines are together>

```css
.container-content .main-content .container-test pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  word-break: break-all;
  color: #ececec;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2471A3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-test">
<pre>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
<blockquote>test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst</blockquote>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set the display property of blockquote (please use better selector) as inline-block.

```css
 .container-test pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.container-test pre blockquote {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2471A3;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-test">
<pre>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
<blockquote>test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst </blockquote>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: @gmpatzer I wasn't asking you, I was asking whoever downvoted my answer :P

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, but it is a good practice to add an explanation to your answer, not just *do this* or *try this*. Why is it showing the gap, and why changing it to `inline-block` fixes that? With a good explanation, your answer will be more useful to future readers and will likely attract more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have an extra `br` after your blockquote is because you're using the `<pre>` tag. The `pre` tag formats the text exactly like how you write it in the code. So you have two solutions here

1. Format code like how you want it to look

```css
.container-test {
  font-family: monospace;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2471A3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-test">
<pre>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
<blockquote>test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst</blockquote>test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
</pre>
</div>
```

2. Avoid using `pre` entirely, and add a width to your container.

```css
.container-test {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 150px;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  border-left: 3px solid #2471A3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-test">
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
<blockquote>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
</blockquote>
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
test test tesst
</div>
```

You can read more about the `pre` tag [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_pre_tag.htm).

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer, (as it doesn't provide a fix) also external links are not a good idea

Comment: Errr if you read the whole paragraph links are encouraged as a reference to external material not as the source of the answer. If you provide a more complete description (with perhaps some code snippets in this case) of how pre behaves, and *then* say here is more information (also probably better to use w3c rather than a tutorial website as reference point) then it would be in the spirit of [so], meanwhile if you like we can discuss this on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1):

You can set

```
blockquote {
  /* your other styles */
  display: inline;
}
```